# Cp big files with interaction in ksh

Tags: ksh, cp

I'm tring to copy files bigger than 10 mega, but with a user interaction (are you sure, you want to copy this file ?)

I tried :

```
find . -name "*.log" -size +10485760c -exec cp -i {} $3/$2/ \;
```

But, I only get the msg while overwriting. What else can I do to have the same also with writing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate that into `find -exec`, you'll have to spawn a shell:

```
find . -name "*.log" -size +10485760c -exec sh -c '
    printf "are you sure you want to copy %s (y/n) ? " "$0"
    read ans
    [[ $ans == [yY]* ]] && cp "$0" "$1"
' {} "$3/$2/" \;
```